# c# check if key exists in dictionary then pass on its value

Tags: c#, dictionary

In my desktop `C#` application I start with a dictionary. I want to be able to check this dictionary for a key. If the dictionary has this key, I would like to pass it on to a method. If the dictionary doesn't have this key, I would like to create a blank list and just pass that on instead. How can I do this?

I get the error "given key was not present in the dictionary". Can I add a default so it is never null maybe?

```
// myDic was declared as a Dictionary<string, List<string>    

// Here is how I call someFunction
string text = SomeFunction(stringValue1, stringValue2, myDic[field1.field2]);

// SomeFunction looks like this
string SomeFunction (string string1, string string2, List<string> ra) 
{  
     // method 
     return stringResult;
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Where does it occur?

Comment: What do you mean by "it errors"? What error do you get? My first guess would be that `myDic[field1.field2]` fails, because there is no key in the dictionary that corresponds to `field1.field2`.

Comment: If `field1.field2` may not be in `myDic`, then *test* that before using it!

Comment: Yes that is exactly right.  There is no data in the dictionary.  But I need to pass a dictionary so I need to know how to get some default data in it so I can test it later.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Updated based on comments. To pass one key that may or may not exist you may do this(assuming the value is a List):

```
// assuming the method we are calling is defined like this:
// public String SomeFunction(string string1, String string2, List<String> ra)  

List<string> valueToPassOn;
if (_ra.ContainsKey(lc.Lc))
{
     valueToPassOn = _ra[lc.Lc]
}
else
{
     valueToPassOn = new List<string>(); 
}

string text = tooltip.SomeFunction(something1, something2, valueToPassOn);
```

Should you want to pass an entire dictionary (as the question originally read), regardless of whether or not the dictionary exists:

You have two options. Either create the dictionary regardless like this:

```
if (myDic == null)
{
     // change var and var2 to the types of variable they should be, ex:
     myDic = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
}
string text = SomeFunction(stringValue1, stringValue2, myDic);
```

or, what is probably the better option, in the declaration of the function SomeFunction add a dictionary as a variable with a default parameter. Just be sure that your function knows what to do if the dictionary is null.

```
string SomeFunction(string string1, string string2, Dictionary dictionary = null)
{
     // method here
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can check if the key exists using `ContainsKey` method and if it returns false you can pass a `default` value you want:

```
// replace default(string) with the value you want to pass
// if the key doesn't exist
var value = myDic.ContainsKey(field1.field2) ? myDic[field1.field2] : default(string);
string text = SomeFunction(stringValue1, stringValue2, value);
```

Comment: Thanks so much Selman22.  This is what I needed I think.  Going to try it.

Comment: when i do obj.ContainsKey(HaveRange) then i get an error CS1061: 'ClassName' does not contain a definition for 'ContainsKey' and no accessible extension method 'ContainsKey' accepting a first argument of type 'FilterInformation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 7):

What you need to do is make sure the dictionary actually contains the given key in the dictionary.

If you need to extract the value by key, use `TryGetValue` method:

```
string value;
if (myDict.TryGetValue(key, out value))
{
    // Key exists in the dictionary, do something with value.
}
```

Comment: This method is more efficient then the current selected answer as the keys collection is only traversed once

Comment: With C#7 you can do: myDict.TryGetValue(key, out string value)

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the following snippets in order to check if dictionary is empty and take some action:

```
var x = new Dictionary<string, string>();

if (x.Any())
{
    //....
}

if (x.ContainsKey("my key"))
{

}

if (x.ContainsValue("my value"))
{

}

if (x.Count > 0)
{

}
```